# Email input form not showing/working properly in different browsers

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

I have a simple form which only has two input controls: a text box for taking emails, and a submit button.

**HTML:**

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email here..." required>
  <button type="submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/aDhUL/

**Form has issues in different browsers:**

- Chrome: Works & displays fine.
- iPhone: Works & displays fine.
- Firefox 22: `placeholder` text not shown, and cannot type anything in
  the textbox too !
- Internet Explorer 10: Works fine, but `placeholder` text is cropped !

How can I make it cross-browser compatible guys ?

I've tried removing the `placeholder` and `required` parameters to make it very simple, but still it doesn't work on Firefox ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is with your CSS styling.
You have set the height of the input as 0px. So the input box accepts the input but is not displayed in FF due to the height set to zero.

Your Previous Code is here:

```
 .form-wrapper input {
            width: 150px;
            height: 0px;
            padding: 10px 5px;
```

New JSFiddle with height set to 10px is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B435n/): http://jsfiddle.net/B435n/

And you can use any jQuery plugin for placeholder thing.

Comment: Had to re-arrange the heights a little, but yes, that was indeed the problem !

Answer (score 1):

I think you try to run "placeholder" in all browser.
then just attach one .js file that as follow it work Fine in all browser.

```
;(function(window, document, $) {

    var isInputSupported = 'placeholder' in document.createElement('input'),
        isTextareaSupported = 'placeholder' in document.createElement('textarea'),
        prototype = $.fn,
        valHooks = $.valHooks,
        hooks,
        placeholder;

    if (isInputSupported && isTextareaSupported) {

        placeholder = prototype.placeholder = function() {
            return this;
        };

        placeholder.input = placeholder.textarea = true;

    } else {

        placeholder = prototype.placeholder = function() {
            var $this = this;
            $this
                .filter((isInputSupported ? 'textarea' : ':input') + '[placeholder]')
                .not('.placeholder')
                .bind({
                    'focus.placeholder': clearPlaceholder,
                    'blur.placeholder': setPlaceholder
                })
                .data('placeholder-enabled', true)
                .trigger('blur.placeholder');
            return $this;
        };

        placeholder.input = isInputSupported;
        placeholder.textarea = isTextareaSupported;

        hooks = {
            'get': function(element) {
                var $element = $(element);
                return $element.data('placeholder-enabled') && $element.hasClass('placeholder') ? '' : element.value;
            },
            'set': function(element, value) {
                var $element = $(element);
                if (!$element.data('placeholder-enabled')) {
                    return element.value = value;
                }
                if (value == '') {
                    element.value = value;
                    // Issue #56: Setting the placeholder causes problems if the element continues to have focus.
                    if (element != document.activeElement) {
                        // We can't use `triggerHandler` here because of dummy text/password inputs :(
                        setPlaceholder.call(element);
                    }
                } else if ($element.hasClass('placeholder')) {
                    clearPlaceholder.call(element, true, value) || (element.value = value);
                } else {
                    element.value = value;
                }
                // `set` can not return `undefined`; see http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.7.1/val#L2363
                return $element;
            }
        };

        isInputSupported || (valHooks.input = hooks);
        isTextareaSupported || (valHooks.textarea = hooks);

        $(function() {
            // Look for forms
            $(document).delegate('form', 'submit.placeholder', function() {
                // Clear the placeholder values so they don't get submitted
                var $inputs = $('.placeholder', this).each(clearPlaceholder);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $inputs.each(setPlaceholder);
                }, 10);
            });
        });

        // Clear placeholder values upon page reload
        $(window).bind('beforeunload.placeholder', function() {
            $('.placeholder').each(function() {
                this.value = '';
            });
        });

    }

    function args(elem) {
        // Return an object of element attributes
        var newAttrs = {},
            rinlinejQuery = /^jQuery\d+$/;
        $.each(elem.attributes, function(i, attr) {
            if (attr.specified && !rinlinejQuery.test(attr.name)) {
                newAttrs[attr.name] = attr.value;
            }
        });
        return newAttrs;
    }

    function clearPlaceholder(event, value) {
        var input = this,
            $input = $(input);
        if (input.value == $input.attr('placeholder') && $input.hasClass('placeholder')) {
            if ($input.data('placeholder-password')) {
                $input = $input.hide().next().show().attr('id', $input.removeAttr('id').data('placeholder-id'));
                // If `clearPlaceholder` was called from `$.valHooks.input.set`
                if (event === true) {
                    return $input[0].value = value;
                }
                $input.focus();
            } else {
                input.value = '';
                $input.removeClass('placeholder');
                input == document.activeElement && input.select();
            }
        }
    }

    function setPlaceholder() {
        var $replacement,
            input = this,
            $input = $(input),
            $origInput = $input,
            id = this.id;
        if (input.value == '') {
            if (input.type == 'password') {
                if (!$input.data('placeholder-textinput')) {
                    try {
                        $replacement = $input.clone().attr({ 'type': 'text' });
                    } catch(e) {
                        $replacement = $('<input>').attr($.extend(args(this), { 'type': 'text' }));
                    }
                    $replacement
                        .removeAttr('name')
                        .data({
                            'placeholder-password': true,
                            'placeholder-id': id
                        })
                        .bind('focus.placeholder', clearPlaceholder);
                    $input
                        .data({
                            'placeholder-textinput': $replacement,
                            'placeholder-id': id
                        })
                        .before($replacement);
                }
                $input = $input.removeAttr('id').hide().prev().attr('id', id).show();
                // Note: `$input[0] != input` now!
            }
            $input.addClass('placeholder');
            $input[0].value = $input.attr('placeholder');
        } else {
            $input.removeClass('placeholder');
        }
    }

}(this, document, jQuery));
```

and then just put one script on page.

```
<script>

   $(function() {

    $('input, textarea').placeholder();

    });
  </script>
```

It Work Fine in All Browser (placeholder)